# binary search C

Tags: c, arrays, search, binary

Here's the signature of the binary search function:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

I don't understand why we're sending a void* as the array pointer, instead of void**, since as far as I know, if i'm looking for an int inside an int array, I should send an int* as the array, not int...
Would the implementaion be much different (or perhaps impossible to implement) if the function's signature was like this:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void** base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bsearch()` function is pretty flexible, because you can pass a pointer to *any* kind of array. Changing the `base` parameter to `const void **base` would imply that you could only use `bsearch()` on arrays of pointers.

If you are searching an array of `int`, then you should certainly pass a `void *` which is the start address of your array.